# I'm attempting to populate a listbox by calling a stored procedure - only getting null values

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've successfully run my SQL Server stored procedure and returned values but when I attempt to call it from the C# WPF application, it is only returning null values. The error I'm getting is that the `GetAllAirports()` is only returning null values. I double checked my server name was right so I'm stuck.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetAllAirport1]
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

    SELECT 
        GEOLOCATION.Lat, GEOLOCATION.Long, 
        IACOCODE, IATACODE, STRNAME, STRCITY, INT_ELEVATION 
    FROM 
        TBL_AIRPORT AIR
    JOIN 
        TBL_COUNTRY C ON C.COUNTRY_ID = AIR.COUNTRY_FK
    WHERE 
        GEOLOCATION.Lat <> 0 OR GEOLOCATION.Long <> 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    DECLARE @ERRORMESSAGE NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @ERSEVERITY INT, 
            @ERSTATE INT

    SELECT @ERRORMESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
           @ERSEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
           @ERSTATE = ERROR_STATE()

    IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    RAISERROR(@ERRORMESSAGE, @ERSEVERITY, @ERSTATE)
END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

And here's my C# code to call it;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public class DataAccess
    {
        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            String ConnectionString = "Server=AL75FA\\L;Database=DB_AIRPORTS;Trusted_connection=Yes;";
            return ConnectionString;
        }

        public List<Location.Location> GetAllAirports()
        {
            List<Location.Location> Templist = new List<Location.Location>();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader T = PDM.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(GetConnectionString(), "dbo.SP_GetAllAirport1");

            if (T.HasRows)
            {
                while (T.Read())
                {
                    Location.Location tempAirport = new Location.Location(Convert.ToDouble(T[0]), (Convert.ToDouble(T[1])), (Convert.ToDouble(T[6])), (Convert.ToString(T[2])));
                    Templist.Add(tempAirport);

                    try { }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //swallow
                    }
                }

                return Templist;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

And the xaml window:

```
using DataAccess;
using Location;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AirportReader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private DataAccess.DataAccess DataLayer;
        private List<Location.Location> AirportList;

        private void LB_AIRPORT_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Location.Location TemporaryAirport in AirportList)
            {
                String TempString = " " + TemporaryAirport.GetAirportCode() + " Latitude: " + TemporaryAirport.GetLatitude() + " Longitude: " + TemporaryAirport.GetLongitude();
                LB_AIRPORT.Items.Add(TempString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: If you debug your code, can you check whether or not you're actually getting back any values from the database? Is it "just" a display problem, or is really nothing being loaded from the database?

Comment: I believe nothing is actually being loaded from my database. When I debug and hover over the AirportList it says values=null. Where it should be around 1000 values.

Comment: Update: After adding the changes that were mentioned below when debugging it now tells me that DataAccess.GetAllAirports() not all code paths return a value. Could it be an issue with my stored procedure? I ran it in SQL and it returns the correct values so I thought it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your object `AirportList` never calls `GetAllAirports()`. It is only initialized, but no values are ever assigned to it. Hence the NULL values you must be getting on `TemporaryAirport.GetAirportCode()`, `TemporaryAirport.GetLatitude()` and `TemporaryAirport.GetLongitude()`.

Notwithstanding the namespaces, maybe a simple `AirportList = DataLayer.GetAllAirports();` would solve your problem.

And wouldn't it be easier to declare `GetAllAiports()` as `static` ?

Comment: Ive added the AirportList=DataLayer.GetAllAirports(); and it got rid of the error that MainWindow AirportList is never assigned so thank you! I am still getting an error that Field MainWindow.DataLayer is never assigned and will always return a null value. This must be the issue but what am I assigning it to? Would I need to add it in event handler?

Comment: Update! I changed DataAccess.DataAccess DataLayer(); to DataAccess.DataAccess DataLayer=  new DataAccess.DataAccess();

Comment: Which got rid of my warning about Field MainWindow.DataLayer returning null values, but unfortunately I am still only returning null values

Comment: Actually it is now giving me the error that not all code paths return a value. which much be an issue with my connection or procedure?

Comment: Indeed, the only return path is conditioned by `if (T.HasRows)`. If it is not true, then you don't return anything. You could add a `return null`at the end, but then you need to make sure that you treat the null case before using the result. For your other problem, make `GetConnectionString()` private, and `GetAllAirports()` static, so you can use it without initializing a DataAccess class. You can get rid of `private DataAccess.DataAccess DataLayer;`, and just use `AirportList = DataAccess.GetAllAirports();`